# Cannot get this MasterDetail to work with Prism and listview

Tags: xamarin, prism

Below is my code that does not work could you spot what is wrong?

I am trying to convert this to prism
https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/Navigation/MasterDetailPage

I keep getting

"System.InvalidOperationException:
PushAsync is not supported globally on Android, please use a NavigationPage."

I am using a navigationpage(I think I do)

Could somebody look at the code .Below is all the code and tell me what Am I doing wrong??

many thanks!

app.cs

```
public partial class App : PrismApplication
        {
            public App(IPlatformInitializer initializer = null) : base(initializer) { }

            protected override void OnInitialized()
            {
                   InitializeComponent();

                    NavigationService.NavigateAsync("MainPage/Navigation/ContactsPage");                        
            }

            protected override void RegisterTypes()
            {
                //Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<NavigationPage>("Navigation");
                Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<MainNavigationPage>("Navigation");

                Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<MainPage,MainPageViewModel>();

                Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<ContactsPage,ContactsPageViewModel>();
                Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<MasterPage,MasterPageViewModel>();
                Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<ReminderPage,ReminderPageViewModel>();
                Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<TodoListPage,TodoListPageViewModel>();

            }
        }
```

MainNavigationPage.Xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <NavigationPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                    xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
                    prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
                    x:Class="MasterDetailReferenceApp.Views.MainNavigationPage">

    </NavigationPage>
```

MainPage.Xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
        <MasterDetailPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                     xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
                     xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MasterDetailReferenceApp.Views;assembly=MasterDetailReferenceApp"
                     prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
                     x:Class="MasterDetailReferenceApp.Views.MainPage"
                     Title="MainPage">
           <MasterDetailPage.Master>
    <views:MasterPage x:Name="masterPage" />
</MasterDetailPage.Master>
<MasterDetailPage.Detail>
    <NavigationPage>
        <x:Arguments>
            <views:ContactsPage />
        </x:Arguments>
    </NavigationPage>
</MasterDetailPage.Detail>
```

MainPage.cs

```
public partial class MainPage : MasterDetailPage,IMasterDetailPageOptions
        {
            public MainPage()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            public bool IsPresentedAfterNavigation => Device.Idiom != TargetIdiom.Phone;
        }

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                 xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
                 prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
                 x:Class="MasterDetailReferenceApp.Views.MasterPage"             
                 Icon="hamburger.png"
                 Title="Personal Organiser">
        <ContentPage.Content>
            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                <ListView x:Name="listView" 
                          RowHeight="60"
                          SeparatorVisibility="None"
                          BackgroundColor="White"  
                          HasUnevenRows="true"
                          ItemSelected="OnMenuItemSelected">
                          >
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ImageCell Text="{Binding Title}" ImageSource="{Binding IconSource}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </StackLayout>
        </ContentPage.Content>
    </ContentPage>
```

MasterPage.cs

```
 public partial class MasterPage : ContentPage
    {
        public ListView ListView => listView;

        public MasterPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var masterPageItems = new List<MasterPageItem>();
            masterPageItems.Add(new MasterPageItem
            {
                Title = "Contacts",
                //Uri = "ContactsPage",
                Uri = "Navigation/ContactsPage",
                IconSource = "contacts.png",
                TargetType = typeof(ContactsPage)
            });
            masterPageItems.Add(new MasterPageItem
            {
                Title = "TodoList",
                Uri = "Navigation/TodoListPage",
                //Uri = "TodoListPage",
                IconSource = "todo.png",
                TargetType = typeof(TodoListPage)
            });
            masterPageItems.Add(new MasterPageItem
            {
                Title = "Reminders",
                Uri = "Navigation/RemindersPage",
                IconSource = "reminders.png",
                TargetType = typeof(ReminderPage)
            });


            listView.ItemsSource = masterPageItems;
        }

        private void OnMenuItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var item = (MasterPageItem)e.SelectedItem;

            ((MasterPageViewModel)BindingContext).NavigateCommand.Execute(item.Uri);

        }
    }
```

MasterPageItem

```
public class MasterPageItem
            {
                public string Title { get; set; }
                public string Uri { get; set; }
                public string IconSource { get; set; }
            }
```

Comment: When do the exception occur? After start app? Or when click of left menu?
 Changing in App.cs NavigationService.NavigateAsync("MainPage/Navigation/ContactsPage"); to "MainPage/MainNavigationPage/ContactsPage" will help?

Comment: Thanks for spotting that but still same error

Answer (score 0):

You need to set some NavigationPage as Detail for MasterDetailPage. Like this:

```
    <MasterDetailPage.Detail>
        <NavigationPage BarTextColor="White">
            <x:Arguments>
                <local:StatisticsPage />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
    </MasterDetailPage.Detail>
```

In this example first page in navigation page will be StatisticsPage.
Then, from StatisticsPageViewModel you can do

```
await _navigationService.NavigateAsync(new Uri(navParam, UriKind.Relative), useModalNavigation: isModal);
```

where navParam is `nameof(SettingsPage)`. That will switch NavigationPage content to SettingsPage.
If you want to navigate away from MasterDetailPage then do

```
await NavigationService.NavigateAsync(nameof(OtherNonMasterDetailPage));
```

from your MasterDetailPageViewModel (not from the NavigationPage content's view model)

Comment: thanks for your reply .It's driving me mad.see edited question I have modified the masterDetail page but I still get the same error when I select a page from menu. that is the only change I made

Comment: `protected override void OnInitialized()
            {
                   InitializeComponent();

                    NavigationService.NavigateAsync(nameof(MainPage));                        
            }`

Comment: Still same error.. happy to email solution or upload somewhere